# Bun set breakpoints in tests

Tags: testing, breakpoints, bun

I have this simple test, but when I run `bun test`, the `debugger` is never triggered...

Is there a way to set breakpoints in Bun tests??

```
import { describe, expect, test, beforeAll } from "bun:test";
import { Sudoku } from "../sudoku"

describe("Sudoku", () => {
  test("row", () => {
    let sudoku = new Sudoku()
    debugger
    expect(sudoku.row(0)).toEqual([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
    expect(sudoku.row(1)).toEqual([2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `--inspect-brk` flag to pause at debugger statements. You find related documentation [here](https://bun.sh/docs/runtime/debugger). This automatically adds a debugger to the first like of code.

Note: Make sure to enable the `debugger statements` flag under `Breakpoints` on the left panel of the inspector to pause at `debugger` statements.

[image: sample inspector]